# Is there a good resource for design patterns when working with NoSQL?

Tags: design-patterns, nosql

Is this even a reasonable question to ask? I know most NoSQL databases all have different ontology which make them more suitable for certain parts of your design stack.

I know there are four big types of NoSQL:

1. Key-value
2. Column
3. Document
4. Graph-oriented

I'm currently struggling to grasp the use cases and comparative advantages between these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each type adheres to a different type of problem.

There's some theoretical discussion here:

http://builds.hibernatingrhinos.com/download/1468

Other SO questions contain more info on NoSQL, you can probably do some digging here too.

Comment: that paper was an extremely helpful resource. alas, i only have but one upvote to give :)

Answer (score 0):

here some patterns that you may or may not find useful

https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/wiki/Patterns-Page